# problem in Error handling method in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception

I am using Error Handling Method globally in appDelegate method to caught exceptions.

Code:

//In appDelegate.m

```
 static void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) 
  {
   printf("\n ===== In uncaughtExceptionHandler Method =======");

  NSArray *stack = [exception callStackReturnAddresses];
  NSLog(@"========  Exception *************%@", stack);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Exception Occured"
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];   
        [alert release];

  }

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary 
 *)launchOptions 
  {    

 // Override point for customization after application launch.
 NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);


 }
```

I am implementing an Alert in the uncaughtExceptionHandler Method. But I am getting Error as
  "self " undeclared.

Can Anyone Please Suggest how to implement Alert when the uncaughtExceptionHandler is
   called.

thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this [Handle Uncaught Exception](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

`self` is undefined within a `C` function. If you want to make the application delegate the delegate for your alert view then you should probably replace `self` with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`.

Comment: @Lakshmi Did this help? Do you need further assistance on this?